# How to check if two subspaces are the same.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose I have some $N$ dimensional real vector space and two $M<N$ dimensional subspaces of that, and say I know one set a basis vectors for each: ${v_i}$ where $i=1,2,...,M$ and ${w_i}$ where $i=1,2,...,M$.  How can I check if these subspaces are the same or not?

Comment: It suffices if $v_i\in Span(\{w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_M\})$ for each $i$.

Comment: @vadim123 This comment is an answer and should be posted as such.

Comment: @AlexG. it's not clear that this is the kind of answer OP is looking for, and a comment is a good way to probe.  It's reasonable to post a comment like that and wait for a response such as "what does any of that mean?" or "why is that sufficient?" or "but what computation should I perform?".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments." If your answer is not the answer OP was looking for, OP can say so and you can adjust your answer. When we leave comments like these and OP is satisfied but doesn't say anything, the question looks like it is unanswered, even though it's not.

Comment: @AlexG, you missed the third reason to comment, to [add minor or transient information](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).  My goal was, as omnomnomnom points out, to try to clarify what is being asked, and to bring OP into that conversation.  If you feel that this is a full answer, then by all means *you* should post it as such.

Comment: I would let $A$ be an $N\times 2M$ with (ordered) columns $v_1,...,v_M,w_1,...,w_M$. Then your two subspaces are equal if and only if $\text{rank}(A)=M$. So compute $\text{rref}(A)$ and then count the number of non zero rows. Of course this only works if your vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^N$ but you can apply the same argument on $[v_j]_\beta,[w_j]_\beta$ where $\beta$ is an ordered basis of your universal vector space.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the subspaces $V$ and $W$, respectively. Recall that if $v_1, \ldots, v_M \in W$, then since $W$ is a subspace, $V = \text{Span}(v_1, \ldots, v_M) \subset W$. Since $V$ and $W$ have the same dimension, this implies that $V = W$.

Note that it would be equivalent to check that each $w_i$ is in $V$.